# What is the difference between "Aha!", "Ouch!", "Phew!" and "Aah!"

Tags: word-choice, differences, exclamations

I was confused what to use in gap **11**.

Kindly after going through the passage answer the following 4 questions and in question 3 please explain why you have chosen any option and what is the difference between those four options.

**The passage**

> I peered at the river through a gap in the roots of the strangler fig. The thick branches of the tree **9** me without really protecting me. I noticed the gentlest of ripples in the water and then something **10** began to emerge from its depths. An enormous head upon a slender neck rose above the surface. I looked into the beast's cold, reptilian eyes.I could sense no mind or soul behind them. I had to refrain from letting out a frightened **11**! The time for retreating into the depths of the forest had arrived and I knew that it was **12**.

*1.* Which of these fits gap **9**.

(a) hidden
(b) was hiding
(c) were hiding
(d) hiding

*2.* Which of these fits gap **10**.

(a) wonderful yet grand
(b) amazing yet astonishing
(c) magnificent yet terrifying
(d) frightening yet scary

*3.* Which of these fits gap **11**.

(a) "Aha"!
(b) "Ouch!"
(c) "Phew!"
(d) "Aah!"

*4.* Which of these fits gap **12**.

(a) neither now nor newer
(b) neither sooner nor later
(c) either sooner rather than later
(d) either now or never

Comment: Welcome to ELU! It's not relevant to your question, but I think your 4-(d) is a typo and should be "either now or **never**".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***"Aah"*** - Surprised/Scared - the answer to your questions

"Aha" - Enlightened - *Aha! That is how!*

"Ouch" - Hurt by something - *Ouch!, you hurt me*

"Phew" - Relieved - *Phew!, that was close*